# Can we recover all matrix minors from some of them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, determinant, exterior-algebra

Let $k,n$ be natural numbers, $1<k<n$. Suppose we have an "unknown"  **invertible** $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over a field of characteristic zero. (we do not know the entries of $A$).

> Can we recover all the $k$-minors of $A$ from a *fixed, ordered* partial list of them?

That is, suppose that we are given the values of $r$ of the minors- i.e. we are given an *indexed* list of $r$ numbers, and we are told which number corresponds to which minor. Can we recover the other minors?

**Comment:**

Some non-degeneracy conditions on $A$ are necessary here: We at least need to assume that $\text{rank}(A)>k$. Otherwise, if $\text{rank}(A)\le k$, then even if we know all the $k$-minors of $A$ except one, we cannot recover the last unknown minor.

Indeed, take $A=\pmatrix{D&0\\ 0&0}$ where $D$ is any diagonal matrix of size $k$. We can't recover the $k$-minor corresponding to the first $k$ rows and columns (which is $\det D$) from the other $k$-minors (which are zeroes). This example was suggested by [user1551](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274711/how-many-matrix-minors-determine-all-the-minors#comment6734361_3274711).

Comment: This example may be of interest: for $A=\pmatrix{D&0\\ 0&0}$, where $D$ is any diagonal matrix of size $k=n-1$. We cannot recover the $(n,n)$-th $k$-minor (i.e. $\det D$) from the others (which are zeroes).

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice observation. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Does a $k$-minor here means the determinant of any $k\times k$ submatrix, or only the principal submatrices formed by repeatedly deleting the same-indexed row and column?

Comment: @Joppy It means the determinant of any $k \times k$ submatrix.

Comment: The question has now been asked on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346074/can-we-recover-all-k-minors-of-a-square-matrix-from-some-of-them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Assume that you are interested in $k$-minors, what you're going to do is focus on submatrices of $A$ of size $k\times n$ by eliminating $n-k$ rows. Such a $k\times n$ submatrix has $n\choose k$ $k$-minors, and these are subject to what is known as Plücker equations:

> **Theorem:** an ordered collection of $n\choose k$ integers is the collection of (lexicographically ordered) maximal minors of some
>   $k\times n$ matrix if and only if these numbers satisfy a set of polynomial equations known as
>   Plücker equations.
>
> *Context:* see [these lecture notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ayong/Math595TheGrassmannian/Grlecture1.pdf) by Alexander Yong.
>
> *Proof:* see [Schubert Calculus](http://people.reed.edu/~davidp/pcmi/laksov.pdf) by Kleiman and Lakso.

*In practice, it means that there is some maximal number of $k$-minors that can be fixed independently, after which all the others will be uniquely determined by the equations.*

Plücker equations for $(n,k)$ can be displayed by typing `Grassmannian(k-1,n-1)` into [Macaulay2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) (the $-1$ come from projective reasons).
Here is one of these equations for $n=6, k=3$:
      $$p_{2,3,4} p_{1,3,6} -p_{1,3,4}p_{2,3,6} +p_{1,2,3}p_{3,4,6}=0$$

As expected, if all minors are zero except one of them, then the Plücker equations will be of no help to find that one, as the variables always come by pairs.

---

Part of this answer was borrowed from [this question/answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264205/how-independent-are-the-minors-of-a-matrix), which amazingly was asked just 10 days before yours.