# Existence of an integer matrix with maximal subdeterminants $a_1, \ldots, a_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, integers

Given $n \geq 2$ and integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, does there exist an integer $(n-1) \times n$ matrix whose maximal subdeterminants are $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ (with fixed ordering)?

Example: $n = 3$, $(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (19, 4, 22)$. The matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 11 & 2 \\
-2 &95&19\end{pmatrix}$$

has $i$th subdeterminants (with $i$th column removed) equal to $(19, 4, 22)$.

**Context:**

- The $n=3$ case is precisely this question from the newsletter: [Is every vector in $\mathbb Z^3$ a cross product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428714). (This is where the example comes from.)
- The general case would give an alternative proof for this question: [Can the determinant of an integer matrix with a given row be any multiple of the gcd of that row?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411324) by taking $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ to be coefficients in Bézout's theorem.

Comment: I wonder if this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3266825/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proven inductively as in the second linked question, and it generalizes the construction in the first linked question (which is for $n=3$).

When $n = 2$ we can take the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & a_1\end{pmatrix}$. Now take $n \geq 3$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ integers, and let $d = \gcd(a_2, \ldots, a_n)$. Construct (using the induction hypothesis) a working $(n-2) \times (n-1)$ matrix for $a_2/d, \ldots, a_n/d$ and call it $M$. The maximal subdeterminants of $M$ are coprime, so there exist integers $c_2, \ldots, c_n$ with
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}c_2&\cdots&c_n\\\\
&\large M\end{pmatrix}=a_1 \,.$$
We can then take the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}-d & c_2&\cdots&c_n\\
0 \\
\vdots &&\large M \\
0\end{pmatrix} \,.$$

Comment: This is where I was headed! I worked it out for $n$ = 4 and planned to get into detail for the general case, so thanks! But I'm confused by the comment "The case $n$ = 2 being trivial." Isn't the starting number for the induction $n$=3; and (for $n$ = 2), how would we interpret the matrix with $n$-2 = 0 rows? I have a feeling you are really starting with $n$ = 3, and going down one to 2, but it's not clear to me how this works.

Comment: To clarify, the proof is by induction for $n \geq 2$, and $n = 2$ is the base case (where we can take the matrix $(a_2, a_1)$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that the numbers have gcd $1$.  Let $A$ a matrix of determinant $1$ with first row $(a_1,- a_2,  \ldots, (-1)^{n-1} a_n)$.  Since $\det A =1$  we have $A= \operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj} (A))$ ( see [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)).

$\bf{Added:}$  We can also prove the following result: Consider a $k\times n$ matrix with elements in a PID. Then there exists an $(n-k)\times n$ matrix such that the $n-k$ minors are the same as the corresponding $k$ minors.  Use a similar idea and the [Jacobi formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisTheorem.html) for the minors of the adjugate.